# How to get the value of the decision variables in Gekko-python

Tags: python, gekko

I am using Gekko to solve an optimization models for job assignment, so one of the decision variable (Xijt)(i=workers, j=jobs, t=time periods) is binary whether the worker is selected to the job(x=1) or not (x=0). I got solution (The value of the objective function). However, for the variables value when use - Print(str (x)) - I got all values of x as shown in the attached picture but I want to get only the selected workers where xijt =1.
Same issue with the second variables (Yijt) continues number indicates number of hours for worker i to perform job j at time t. When use - Print(str (Y)) - I got all values of Y but I want to get the Y values for only selected workers where xijt =1. Any idea about resolving that please.
click here for
[output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxGee.png)
and for
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OikwX.jpg)

```
    model = GEKKO()
model.options.SOLVER = 1

x = {}

for i in I:
    for j in J:
        for t in T:
            x[i, j, t] = model.Var(lb=0.00, ub=1.00001,integer=True, name="x %s %s %s" % (i, j, t))
y = {}

for i in I:
    for j in J:
        for t in T:
            y[i, j, t] = model.Var(integer=False, name="y %s %s %s" % (i, j, t))

# model.update()

for l in L:
    for i in I:
        for j in J:
            for t in T:
                model.Equation(x[i, j, t] * (q[i][l] - s[j][l]) >= 0)

for j in J:
    for i in I:
        for t in T:

            model.Equation(x[i, j, t] * (lc[j][t] * y[i, j, t] *  (sum(q[i][l] / s[j][l] for l in L) / len(L))) <= uc[j][t])
            model.Equation(x[i, j, t] * (lz[j][t] * y[i, j, t] * (sum(q[i][l] / s[j][l] for l in L) / len(L))) <= uz[j][t])

for j in J:
    for t in T:
        model.Equation(sum(x[i, j, t] for i in I) == 1)

for i in I:
    for t in T:
        model.Equation(sum(x[i, j, t] for j in J) == 1)

for i in I:
    for t in T:
        model.Equation(sum(y[i, j, t] for j in J) <= 8)

objt = sum(sum(sum((x[i, j, t] * v[j] * lc[j][t]  * y[i, j, t] * (sum(q[i][l] / s[j][l] for l in L) / len(L))) - (
        x[i, j, t] * lz[j][t] * y[i, j, t] *  (sum(q[i][l] / s[j][l] for l in L) / len(L))) for j in J) for i in I) for t in
               T)

model.Obj(-objt)
model.solve(disp=True, debug=False)
print(str (x))
print(str (y))
```

Comment: Please take the effort to paste the code here

Comment: Done, code attached now

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.value[0]` property of the `x` variable. This conditionally retrieves the `y` values if `x` is greater than a threshold value such as `0.9`:

```py
for i in I:
    for j in J:
        for t in T:
            if x[i, j, t].value[0]>=0.9:
                print(y[i, j, t])
```

There is better solution performance by using the Gekko `m.sum()` versus the Python `sum()` function. This shouldn't change the result but it may be much faster.

The array function is also available if you'd like to define the variables this way:

```py
x = m.Array(m.Var,(I,J,T),integer=True,lb=0,ub=1.00001)
y = m.Array(m.Var,(I,J,T),integer=False)
```

It doesn't name the variables but this is not required in Gekko.

Comment: Thank you John for helping. It works well.